# Create Redirect Page For All External Link Blogspot

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, blogger, blogspot

I want make **Some External link Redirect** to my **Specific Page** when leaving my site.
I was try safelink before, but it need to create other **New Blog** to redirect all External Link.

Some thing that I mean, example:
`https://updated2apks.blogspot.co.id/2017/09/whats-different-100-mod-apk.html`

**If click External** link, it will redirect to **Specific Page**

`https://updated2apks.blogspot.com/p/your-apk-is-ready-for-download.html?id=com.qs.whatsdifferent.html`

And Finally **leave the Blog and go to Target link (External)**
Because this is Blogspot platform, I tried search in Google, but it's lack of tutorial. I hope some one here can help me.

Comment: did my question solve your problem, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correct, this is a possible solution, that would redirect the page first to your page and than to the external page.
*(This would have to be done in the Theme)*

**Here is an example:**
*(If the external url uses Parameters or so the code will have to be adapted)*

```
<script>
    // Here we check if the current page is the redirect catch page
    if("http://URL_THAT_SHOULD_CATCH_REDIRECTS.html" === "<data:blog.url/>")
    {
        // Here we assume there is only one parameter in the URL, with our external Link
        var parameter = location.search.split(/\?|=/g).slice(1);
        // Here we check if the size of the array is valid, checking for the parameter name would be also good. Maybe even checking if the passed URL is valid
        if(parameter.length===2){
            // Here we redirekt to the URL that is the Value of the passed parameter
            location.href=parameter[1];
        }

     }
</script>
```

> ### Example result:
>
> ***external URL*** is "www.google.com"
>   ***url to redirect to*** is "great.blogger.com/p/redirect_page.html"
>   ***the a-Tag for the blog*** is `<a href="http://"great.blogger.com/p/redirect_page.html?redirect=www.google.com">LINK</a>`

***Hint:***
If the external url has parameters the url has to be encoded. If the redirect Url has parameters, you have to find the correct parameter, that contains the URL.

***Info:***
If the `href` is set directly to the external page you would need additional Code for creating the correct redirect link, using `EventListener` on the `a`-tag preventing the default behavior and than redirecting in that code. (Here some [Infos on MDN about preventDefault function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault))

**Could look like this:**

```
document.getElementById("aLinkId").addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Here we redirect to the wanted page, with the extra parameter, with the original external URL
    location.href = "REDIRECT_URL?redirect="+ document.getElementById("aLinkId").href; 
});
```

> *All code tested with Chrome 60+*